# iTunes Connect - Technical Role Missing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to add a user with a `Technical` Role to my iTunes Connect account so they can beta test my app through Test Flight, but the `Technical` Role seems to be missing in the following screenshot:

[image]

Did Apple remove this role or change the way Beta Testing works? If so, what did they replace it with?

Answer (score 1):

Use `App Manager` instead of `Technical`. You can also invite beta tester from `Test Flight` --> `External Testers` --> + (Add New). They will be notified to their email. They can download app from `TestFlight` by clicking the app link as provided on email or directly from `TestFlight` notification.

Answer (score 0):

Found this, finally!

> To be eligible to become an internal tester, a user must be part of your iTunes Connect team with the Admin, Technical, App Manager, Developer, or Marketer role.

[TestFlight Beta Testing](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store-connect/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35-SW16)